# How to call javascript in a node.js module from clojurescript?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript

I'm hoping to use the [Coinbase Bitcoin Exchange node.js API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinbase-exchange) from inside ClojureScript.

The goal is to replicate the first javascript example on the page:

```
var CoinbaseExchange = require('coinbase-exchange');
var publicClient = new CoinbaseExchange.PublicClient();
```

But in my following code I've started by trying to access `PublicClient` at all:

```
(ns plutus.core
  (:require
     [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]))

(def coinb (nodejs/require "coinbase-exchange"))
(nodejs/enable-util-print!)

(defn -main [& args]
  (def pc (js/PublicClient.)))
  (println pc))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

This throws a `ReferenceError: PublicClient is not defined`, though I've also tried (along with similar variations):

- `(def pc (. coinb (PublicClient)))`
- `(def pc (.PublicClient coinb))`
- `(def pc (:PublicClient coinb))`

All of which have failed by printing `nil`. I've pretty closely studied [this article](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/) for any relevant examples, but I'm confused on how using node.js affects the naming of things, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really its not a naming issue, its more about how to use `new` with nested properties in an object. Unfortunately, you can't get a reference to `PublicClient` and then `new` that after the fact.

```
(new (.-PublicClient coinb))
```

It does not work even though `(.-PublicClient coinb)` returns a function.

You need to point to the location of the function, by using it's dot notation within ClojureScript:

```
(new coinb.PublicClient)
;; OR, more idiomatic
(coinb.PublicClient.)
```

That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody else seeing this?

```
> ((.-getProducts (cb.PublicClient.)) (fn [_ _ _] nil))
#object[TypeError TypeError: self.makeRelativeURI is not a function]
```